# Visual Studio Community 2015 Edition not building .exe

Tags: build, visual-studio-2015

I am new to C# and I am in my first Hello World program... it runs fine in VS2015 Community Edition (Win 7).  Now, I want to generate an .exe file for my project, but when I click Build ﻿be it in Release or in Debug﻿ I get the message Build Succeeded but I cannot find the .exe file for my project.  I am searching in the same directory where my project resides: I can see the "source" subdirectory and the "artifacts" subdirectory; but cannot see an "release" or nor an  "debug" or  nor an "bin" subdirectories.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are trying to setup a Console Application under the File -> New Project -> Visual C# -> Web Template -> Console (Package). If you are, you need to  use the Visual C# -> Windows -> Console Application.

That will create an .exe file for you.

Comment: Right! what a shame...  Did not see the hint that explains what is a Console(Package) vs a Console Application...